# Delete a node in a Linked list using call by reference

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference

So I'm running into a bit of a wall here. I have a main.c program that plays around with linked lists, and at some points passes in a value of a node that's to be deleted from the list. The kicker was that it was supposed to do it using call by reference. I'm fairly certain (like...85%) that I've got all the things I need for the remove node function, but I'm probably just not implementing it right.

So this is the initializing function that all the others in my List.c file derive from:

```
// Call by reference
// This is a linked list without dummy head node!
void init(List *alist, int (*fComp)(void *, void *), void (*fPrint)(void *), void (*fFree)(void *))
{
    if(alist != NULL)
    {
        alist->head = NULL;
        alist->tail = NULL;
        alist->size = 0;
        alist->cmpData = fComp;
        alist->printData = fPrint;
        alist->freeData = fFree;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid NULL list pointer passed in!\n");
    }
}
```

This is my removeNode function:

```
int removeNode(List *alist, void *obj){
Node *cur, *prev = alist->head, *start = (*alist).head;
void *temp = obj;

if(temp == cur) {
    alist->head = cur->next;
    free(cur);
    return 1;
}

else if(obj != alist->head) {
    for (cur = start->next; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (alist->cmpData(cur->data, temp) == 0) {
            prev->next = cur->next;
            free(cur);
            return 1;
        } // end if
        prev = cur;
    } // end for
} // end else if

return 0;
} // end removeNode
```

"List *alist" and "void *obj" are the linked list elements and the element to be deleted, respectively that are passed in from main.c. The function is supposed to use cmpData (which needs to be passed two void pointers) from the init function to compare the current element being looked at with the element to be deleted then either return 1 if it does delete it or 0 if it doesn't.

Thank you in advanced for any and all help!

***UPDATE*** So my code posting is now the one that I've got to work. It deletes the node as it is supposed to. HOWEVER, do I have enough free() in it? I have a memory leak checking program and it keeps telling me that I need two more free()'s in here, and it seems to specifically be the removeNode function since nowhere else in my program gets flagged.

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what the function does. For example you wrote that function cmpDate either returns 1 or returns 0 but inside function removeNode you check the return value of cmpDate whether it is less than 0.

Comment: Why do you skip to the last node at the start of `removeNode()`?  Also, are you sure you need both `temp` and `prev` set to delete a node (what about deleting the first node)?  When you delete, should you really point `prev->next` to `alist->head->next` or to `temp->next`?  Does `alist->cmpData()` need to be less than zero or just not equal to zero to delete?  How do you get to the next node when you're not deleting the current one?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I just posted a new `removeNode()` function that deletes the node I give it. Though now I'm wondering if I have enough `free()` in there since my memory leak checker flags me for missing two apparently.